# How do I winsorize data in SPSS?

Tags: spss

Does anyone know how to winsorize data in SPSS? I have outliers for some of my variables and want to winsorize them. Someone taught me how to do use the `Transform -> compute variable` command, but I forgot what to do. I believe they told me to just compute the square root of the subjects measurement that I want to winsorize. Could someone please elucidate this process for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [script online to do it already it appears](http://pages.infinit.net/rlevesqu/Syntax/RankingLargestValSortingGrouping/WinsorizeMean.txt). It could perhaps be simplified (the saving to separate files is totally unnecessary), but it should do the job. If you don't need a script and you know the values of the percentiles you need it would be as simple as;

Get the estimates for the percentiles for variable `X` (here I get the 5th and 95th percentile);

```
freq var X /format = notable /percentiles = 5 95.
```

Then lets say (just by looking at the output) the 5th percentile is equal to 100 and the 95th percentile is equal to 250. Then lets make a new variable named `winsor_X` replacing all values below the 5th and 95th percentile with the associated percentile.

```
compute winsor_X = X.
if X <= 100 winsor_X = 100.
if X >= 250 winsor_X = 250.
```

You could do the last part a dozen different ways, but hopefully that is clear enough to realize what is going on when you winsorize a variable.